# Dynamic import in different folder

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-2017

I have some trouble to import dynamicaly a class.

I use alias for this projet :

```
config.resolve.alias = {
    App: path.resolve('./src/'),
    Reactive: path.resolve('./app/')
}
```

I want to import a list of class :

```
const classes = {
    foo: 'App/Foo',
    bar: 'App/Bar'
};
let list = {};
for(var c in classes) {
    (async (k, v, list) => {
        const m = await import(`${v}`);
        list[k] = new m.default();
    })(c, classes[c], list);
}
```

This script is called in `app`, and all imported classes in `src`.

The error is simple : `Cannot find module 'App/Foo'`.

When I check the last entry of error's log :

```
var map = {
    "./OtherClass1": [
        "./app/OtherClass1.js"
    ],
    "./OtherClass1.js": [
        "./app/OtherClass1.js"
    ],
    "./OtherClass2": [
        "./app/OtherClass2.js"
    ],
    "./OtherClass2.js": [
        "./app/OtherClass2.js"
    ]
};
function webpackAsyncContext(req) {
    var ids = map[req];
    if(!ids)
        return Promise.reject(new Error("Cannot find module '" + req + "'."));
    return Promise.all(ids.slice(1).map(__webpack_require__.e)).then(function() {
        return __webpack_require__(ids[0]);
    });
};
webpackAsyncContext.keys = function webpackAsyncContextKeys() {
    return Object.keys(map);
};
webpackAsyncContext.id = "./app lazy recursive ^.*$";
module.exports = webpackAsyncContext;
```

So, the error is legit, because the `map` does not contain `Foo` and `Bar` classes in `src`, only those in `app`.

How can I specify to Webpack to check in both folders, recursively?

But, when I test this, it's work fine :

```
for(var c in classes) {
    (async (k, v, list) => {
        const m = await import(`${"App/Foo"}`);
        list[k] = new m.default();
    })(c, classes[c], list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use react import to import your file and use `file.classname` to call them

**eg** `import claases from '/src';`

and use it link

`app = classes.myfile`

Comment: Thanks but `src` is a folder...Each class is in its own file.

Or I missed something !?

Comment: src in the sense you have to use that file like style.css